# opendir() failing on name with a space, running on linux

Tags: c++, linux, directory, io

My program explores the current directory and all sub directories to print all file names. However, it produces a segmentation fault when a directory has a space in its name. This only occurs on linux - windows it works fine.

The name is stored in `dirent.d_name`, which is a `char[256]`. I have tried using it, converting it to a c-string using `c_str()`, I've tried hard coding the directory name into the code, I've tried escaping the space (although I don't think I'm doing it correctly).

```
int main()
{
    struct dirent *direntry;
    dir = opendir( "hello\ world" );
    print_dir_rec( dir, direntry );
    return 0;
}

void print_dir_rec( DIR *dir, struct dirent *direntry )
{
    while( direntry = readdir(dir) )
    {
        switch( direntry->d_type )
        {
            case DT_DIR:
                DIR *sub_dir = opendir( direntry->d_name );
                print_dir_rec( sub_dir , direntry );
                break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `dname` is storage owned by `readdir` (and is likely reused), you can copy from it to save the name in other storage, but you cannot convert or do anything to the `dname` member itself, it is simply overwritten with the next name.

Comment: I meant I've tried constructing a string from dname and then passing string.c_str() instead of dname

Comment: Generally you want storage that remains in scope for the entire recursive call, e.g. `char path[1024];`, then create the path with `snprintf`, e.g. with the current directory in `name`, you can use `snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);` No have your function take a `const char*` instead of `DIR *dir`, e,g, `print_dir_rec(const char *name)` and make your recursive call `print_dir_rec(path)`.

Comment: You never call `closedir()` when done?

Comment: And if you can use C++17, [std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) makes this nice and simple. There's also the Boost.Filesystem version for older versions of C++.

Comment: The backslash is not required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into problems by passing a `DIR*` pointer and `struct dirent*` pointer as parameters instead of simply forming and passing the next path to open. You want to handle the opening of the directory within the recursive function itself, not as a single pointer passed from `main()`, e.g.

```
void print_dir_rec(const char *name)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            printf("[%s]\n", entry->d_name);
            print_dir_rec(path);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

(**note:** you can adjust the number of chars provided for `path` as needed or by using the `PATH_MAX` macro)

That way, there is no single pointer that is reused throughout every recursive call causing problems. A short example that lists all directories under the current could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void print_dir_rec(const char *name)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            printf("[%s]\n", entry->d_name);
            print_dir_rec(path);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void) {
    print_dir_rec(".");
    return 0;
}
```

Look at how the opening and reading is handled and what information is required to be passed. By providing storage for `path` within each recursive call, you guarantee the name remains in scope until that recursive call returns.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfect! Can you expand a little on snprintf()? What exactly does it do and why is it necessary?

Comment: (sorry had to pick kids up), `sprintf` allows you to write a *formatted-string* to a buffer (`path`) in this case. In order to combine the new directory with the current path, you have to place the *directory-separator* between them. That's where `sprintf` (or `snprintf` as used above) come into play. The format string `"%s/%s"` allows you to place `'/'` between the two string adding the new dirname to the end of the current path. In C++ you can do the same with `std::string` simply concatenating the strings instead. (though a fixed array with automatic storage duration will be more efficient)